# Overlapping axis tick labels in logarithmic plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that worked very well a year or so ago using pyplot; I made a plot using `plt.plot(x,y)` using a logarithmic y-axis and replaced the y-axis ticks and tick labels with a custom set as follows:

```
# set the axis limits
Tmin = -100  # min temperature to plot
Tmax = 40    # max temperature
Pmin = 100   # min pressure
Pmax = 1000  # max pressure
plt.axis([Tmin, Tmax, Pmax, Pmin])

# make the vertical axis a log-axis
plt.semilogy()

# make a custom list of tick values and labels
plist = range(Pmin,Pmax,100)
plabels = []
for p in plist:
    plabels.append(str(p))

plt.yticks(plist,plabels)
```

After recently updating my python installation to the current version of miniconda, I now find that while the new labels still appear, they are partly overwritten by matplotlib's default labels in scientific notation.  So it appears that whereas the above code used to *replace* the default ticks and labels, it now merely *adds* to them.

What do I have to do regain the desired behavior?  And why did it change in the first place?

Comment: Might be a bug.. It only happens for when scale is not linear.

Comment: If it's a bug, is there a workaround?  Also, where does one report possible bugs?

Comment: try at the [github page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you encountered is [a known bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8622) which is [not easy to fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8622#issuecomment-301515510). The core of the problem is the mixing of major and minor ticks; setting the `yticks` redefines the major ticks, and the minor ticks are causing the overlaps.

A workaround until the issue is fixed is to manually disable the minor ticks using `plt.minorticks_off()` (or `ax.minorticks_off()` using the object-oriented API):

```
Tmin = -100  # min temperature to plot
Tmax = 40    # max temperature
Pmin = 100   # min pressure
Pmax = 1000  # max pressure
plt.axis([Tmin, Tmax, Pmax, Pmin])

# make the vertical axis a log-axis
plt.semilogy()
plt.minorticks_off() # <-- single addition

# make a custom list of tick values and labels
plist = range(Pmin,Pmax,100)
plabels = []
for p in plist:
    plabels.append(str(p))

plt.yticks(plist,plabels)
```

[image: result with minor ticks disabled: no overlaps]

As for *when* the change happened: it [came with the default style changes](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#tick-label-formatting) made with matplotlib 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is worth mentionning that the way to label the axes is usually performed automatically. Depending on the range of values to show, different settings apply and the [matplotlib style change](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#tick-label-formatting) to version 2.0 states

> Minor ticks on a log axis are now labeled when the axis view limits span a range less than or equal to the interval between two major ticks.

In that sense the reported behaviour is not really a bug; it is desired.

When it comes to changing the default axes labeling, the use of automatic labeling may still be used. The ticks and labels are created using locators and formatters of `matplotlib.ticker`. The desired plot can be obtained e.g. as follows, where a `MultipleLocator` sets ticks every 100 units and minor ticks are turned of setting a `NullLocator`. To have the ticks formatted as scalar values instead of scientific format, a `ScalarFormatter` can be used.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

plt.axis([-100, 40, 100, 1000])

plt.semilogy()

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(100))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.plot([-100, 40], [100, 1000])
plt.show()
```

[image]

In total this solution is much more versatile than setting the ticks manually via `.yticks`.