# Why can't I remove the default pandas plot logy yticklabels?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Pandas creates default yticklabels for logy plots. I want to replace these labels with my own labels but for some reason I can't seem to remove the default labels.

If I specify the yticks inside the `plot` method, it just writes over the existing default label:

```
x = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
ax = df.plot(logy=True, yticks=[2])
```

Line plot with overwritten labels:
[image: Line plot with overwritten labels]

Trying to remove the yticklabels by referencing the `axes` directly doesn't help either:

```
ax = df.plot(logy=True)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

Line plot with  default labels still there
[image: Line plot with default labels still there]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib plots may have major and minor ticks and ticklabels. In cases where the logarithmic plot ranges over less than a decade, minor ticklabels are set on by default. You may set them to an empty list, via `ax.set_yticklabels([],minor=True)`, or you may turn them off completely via `ax.minorticks_off()`.
Then you can set your custom ticks/-labels to whatever you like.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
ax = df.plot(logy=True)
# turn minor ticklabels off
ax.set_yticklabels([],minor=True)
# or use 
# ax.minorticks_off()
# set new custom ticks/-labels
ax.set_yticks([1,2,2.5])
ax.set_yticklabels(list("ABC"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

There are of course more sophisticated ways to handle ticks and labels, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498157/overlapping-axis-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-plots) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, to remove the default label I set the major labels to empty but not minor ones.

```
ax.set_xticklabels("",major=True)
```